# Django logging error when using daemonize

Tags: python, django, logging

I need to daemonize a django module (using http://noah.org/wiki/Daemonize_Python).

At the start of the daemonize file, I do "import settings" (or "from django.conf import settings") to get the stdout and stderr file names. When I call daemonize with those file names, ALL the logging is done to stderr and nothing is logged in to stdout. Anybody has an idea why it happens?

I use the standard django logging

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined any handlers which log to stderr. See [this example configuration](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/logging-cookbook.html#an-example-dictionary-based-configuration) to see how you can do that.

**Update:** In general, my answer is still correct. You need to provide a handler for the particular stream you want to output to.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, Vinay. I looked at my question and I committed an error in posting (all the logging is going only to the stderr file, and none to the stdout file). Does your answer still holds true in this case?